# How to make your own supply/demand graphs on a computer?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software, economics

This is an econ question but I think you guys might have the solution. I am writing an economics paper and I need to show, in my theory, shifts in the supply and demand that I predict. I don't have any idea, this is just my hypothesis. I just need to make a basic graph (quadrant 1) where I can represent straight lines shifting. How can I do this on a computer?

EDIT: 
Is there any program that does not require numbers? I don't need any numbers---this is all theoretical! 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](http://www.mathe-fa.de/en#result) online tool. The demand curves are a-x (blue). For different values of a, you can draw the corresponding demand curves. If you want additionally different supply curves, you can draw up to thee different supply curves.

My inputs:

a-x (blue)

x-2 (red)

x-1 (green)

a from 8 to 10; incrementing by 2.

The graph can be very well improved by gimp.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [Share$\LaTeX$](https://www.sharelatex.com/) with [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html). It takes some time to get used to, but the folks down at [$\TeX$ Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) can help you out.